# memory leaks caused by assertionLock org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader

Tags: java, tomcat, memory-leaks

In MAT analyzer tool I am finding memory leaks caused by assertionLock `org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader`. Can anyone help me regarding avoiding memory leak by that class?

Comment: The classloader/component "org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader @ 0xc3daba00" occupies 14,467,560 (15.32%) bytes. The memory is accumulated in one instance of "java.util.HashMap$Entry[]" loaded by "<system class loader>".

Keywords
java.util.HashMap$Entry[]
org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader @ 0xc3daba00

Comment: I found above things in MAT Analyzer. Most of the leaks are due to hashmap entry and org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults. Can any one help me to solve this memory leak. Unnecessary memory leaks are causing rather than my application classes and objects.I am trying to resolve this since 2 weeks but unable to find any solution.

Comment: I m facing the same issue. Did anyone find the cause?

Answer (score 0):

Have you resolve this problem now? 
I think you can try to find usage of "org.springframework.beans.CachedIntrospectionResults", maybe you will find some causes.

Answer (score 0):

It is not always a leak. The *reserved memory* shows a memory size which could be garbage collected if the `WebAppClassLoader` would not reference them. The `WebAppClassLoader` has a lifecycle bound to the webapp, and will be stopped/closed when the application stops. Until that it remembers all classes it loaded. The reserved memory then shows how much memory is allocated by objects which are linked to it somehow.

It can be used to access these classes ie. in VisualVM to look which really takes some significiant amount of memory. In my case it was a huge static ConcurrentHashMap used as a cache.